# Using 3D Touch With SpriteKit & Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, touchesmoved, 3dtouch

My goal is to allow the player of my game to open the "gates" farther the harder they press (opening the gates farther allows the player to have an easier time passing through). I have tried using the `force` property. First, I tried using the following code in `touchesBegan`, but the force always registered as `0.0`. Then, I moved it to `touchesMoved`, but this only takes the first touch so `force` is very low. Here is that code:

```
var force: Float

for touch in touches {
    force = touch.force
}

let moveGate = SKAction.moveByX((50.0 * force), y: 0, duration: 5.0)
gate.runAction(moveGate)
```

With that code, the gate will move farther (in the `moveGate` action) the harder you press. However, if you press lightly enough, `touchesMoved` is not even called, or even if it *is* called, `force` is a low number because the beginning of a touch has a light force. And when the code was in `touchesBegan`, `force` was always `0.0`.

I've been tweaking a lot of different things, but I can't get 3D Touch working properly with SpriteKit. That's my question: how do I implement 3D Touch with SpriteKit and Swift so that I can base certain aspects of gameplay based on the force of a single touch?

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you so much in advance for your time!